# Creating an AddRegistration method that returns a boolean value with data validation in C#

Tags: c#, sql, methods, static-methods

I really need help. I can't seem to figure out how to get this AddRegistration Method to work or how to call it to test it. It's supposed to add a row to a table and display a message box saying whether the operation was a success or not. I'll display the code I've written for it.it is supposed to accept a Registration object and return a boolean value that indicates if the operation was successful. I also need to know how I can call it from a Register Product button.

```
public static bool AddRegistration(Registration registration)
{            
    SqlConnection connection = TechSupportDB.GetConnection();
    string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Registrations (CustomerID, ProductCode, RegistrationDate) " +
        "VALUES (@CustomerID, @ProductCode, @RegistrationDate)";
    SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, connection);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", registration.CustomerID);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", registration.ProductCode);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationDate", registration.RegistrationDate);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        int count = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (count > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: write <className>.AddRegistration and pass in Registration registration object.

Comment: Did the assignment not already tell you how to *create an application*?  Really, you need to already have an application (e.g. Console app, Windows Forms app, etc.) to run code in. Once you have an app, you just do what @Amit said.